# Create Versioning in Sharepoint in JAVA

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need versioning in sharepoint.
I used checkout and checkin function , but I am not able to change the content of file. Versioning is created successfully but content is not changed for example In version 1.0 I have content like "Test Demo" and in version 2.0 i have content "Test Demo Change"..
How can I do versioning successfully in sharepoint .?
I used below code

```
boolean checkOutSuccess = service.checkOut("/sites/XXXX/XXXX/XXX/XXX/"+fileName);
                System.out.println("\n out : " + checkOutSuccess);



                boolean checkInSuccess = service.checkIn("/sites/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/"+latestfilename, "Changes");
```

I used com.independentsoft api

How can i resolve this issue?
please help

Comment: Is versioning turned on for the library in question? Versioning needs to be enabled (e.g. through the browser GUI) before SharePoint will start tracking version history for a list or library.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below blog:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467428.aspx
probably,a minor version needs to be checked in with comments.